# p:selectCheckboxMenu ajax 'change' event does not call listener

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, datatable

I am using PrimeFaces editable `p:dataTable`

But When I select from selectCheckboxMenu I not call method event change not trigerred

```
<p:column headerText="Allowed Sec Action" style="width:250px">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectCheckboxMenu multiple="true" value="#{validation.detail.allowedSecAction}" 
                                  collectionType="java.util.ArrayList"  >
                <f:selectItems var="item" itemValue="#{item}" 
                               itemLabel="#{item}" 
                               value="#{emdValidationView.allowedSecActionList}" />
            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="output">
            <p:selectCheckboxMenu multiple="true" value="#{validation.detail.allowedSecAction}" 
                                  collectionType="java.util.ArrayList">
                <p:ajax event="change" update="@form"
                        listener="#{emdValidationView.handleChange()}" />
                <f:selectItems var="item" itemValue="#{item}" 
                               itemLabel="#{item}" 
                               value="#{emdValidationView.allowedSecActionList}" />
            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Does it have a 'change' event? is the behaviour the same when you put 'bla' in there? what about 'select'?

Comment: <p:ajax event="change" update="@form"
                            listener="#{emdValidationView.handleChange()}" /

Comment: @Kukeltje  selectable item "selectCheckboxMenu"

Comment: Yes you **configured** an event called `change`, but what if you put `bla` in there (`event="bla"`) or `select`?

Comment: Oh and it is in the **OUTPUT** facet... That should not be 'editable' at all... only the input facet should be. Might just be undefined behaviour here...

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks I have just seen

Comment: Any progress on this?